# .NetCore: How to include folder in production?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

So I have this code to send email. The code tries to find the `.cshtml` for the email template.

This is my folder hierarchy:

```
Project
-- Email
---- EmailConfirmation.cshtml
---- ResetPassword.cshtml
```

This is the code to find the template:

```
public static string GetEmailTemplate(string templateName)
{
    string path = Path.Combine(Config.Env.ContentRootPath, "Email", templateName);
    string content = "";

    // This text is added only once to the file.
    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        // Create a file to write to.
        content = File.ReadAllText(path);
    } 
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("The email template could not be found");
    }

    return content;
}
```

In `Debug`, this runs perfectly, but in production, the code cannot find the template.

How can I include the template in publish package?

I tried this in my `.csproj`:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="ClientApp\" />
    <Folder Include="Migrations\" />
    <Views Include="Email\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

It is not working.

---

### Edit

I tried to set this:

[image]

But still not working.

Comment: Try this **var path = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Config.Env.ContentRootPath, "Email", templateName));**

Comment: Your approach won't work. Search for `render razor view to string`, or use a library like https://github.com/Tyrrrz/MiniRazor

Comment: If you have zero logic in razor templates, you can mark them as `EmbeddedResource` and read them from assembly at runtime, but if you need to pass it through a render phase, see my previous comment

Answer (score 1):

So my problem was the `Email` folder was not copied to the published package. Add this code to `.csproj`:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Email\EmailConfirmation.cshtml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Email\ResetPassword.cshtml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Or you can set it in the project explorer like this:

[image]

For some reason, the build action has to be set to `None`, because `.NetCore` will treat `Content` differently and the folder will not be copied to the publishing package (maybe the content will be merge into `.dll`, I do not know).

Comment: This looks like it is the working solution. For me it also worked, the **Build Action** should be set to **None**.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this ?

`string workingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;`

`string projectDirectory=Directory.GetParent(workingDirectory).Parent.Parent.FullName;`

It will give you the Path to the project directory. Then you complete with the subdirectory which leads to your file.